# In my website after cycle for {{ some text }} repeated two times

Tags: html, jinja2

In my HTML template I want "In order to get information about this  contact us through ualmaz@gmail.com" printed. But it is repeated two times. I don't know how to get the one I need.

I tried for loop in my view function but still could not fix it.

Here is my HTML:

```
{% for city in cities %}
  {% if city.author.access_challenge %}
    <p class="small text-center"> In order to get information about this  contact us through almaz@protonmail.com </p>
  {% else %}
    <table class="table table-hover text-left col-sm-12" style="table-layout: fixed; word-wrap: break-word;">
     <tbody>
      <tr>
       <td><a class="text-uppercase" href="{% url 'users:address' city.pk %}">{{ city.city }}</a></td>
      </tr>
     </tbody>
    </table>
{% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```

Here is my view function:

```
def cities(request, pk):

    country = Post.objects.get(id=pk).country
    cities = Post.objects.filter(country=country).distinct('city')

    context = {
        'cities':cities,
        'country':country
    }

    return render(request, 'users/cities.html', context)
```

I want `"In order to get information about this  contact us through ualmaz@gmail.com"` printed only one time.

Comment: I guess it's getting printed for each `city` in `cities`. Why not move the line above the for loop?

Comment: I tried. Then nothing will be printed.

Answer (score 0):

How about you move this above the for loop like this and refer to the 1st element of the cities list?

```
{% if cities[0].author.access_challenge %}
    <p class="small text-center"> In order to get information about this  contact us through almaz@protonmail.com </p>
{% else %}
```

Comment: When I do that I get this error: 


`TemplateSyntaxError at /accounts/cabinet/cities/9/

Could not parse the remainder: '[0].author.access_challenge' from 'cities[0].author.access_challenge'`